# Sprites and Arrays as3

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3, sprite

I have a sprite called food which adds to the screen via the use of a timer. more food items are added to the screen over time. How would i hit test all these food sprites with another object? 
(the makeItem function creates the sprite btw)

```
 private function placeFood(event:TimerEvent = null):void{   
        var rndI:uint = Math.floor(Math.random() * DIM);  //sets a random integer based on the the floor
        var rndJ:uint = Math.floor(Math.random() * DIM);

        var rndX:Number = grid[rndI][rndJ].x; // sets a grid position for the food item to go
        var rndY:Number = grid[rndI][rndJ].y;



        food = makeItem(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);// random color
        food.x = rndX;
        food.y = rndY;

        var foodArray:Array = new Array();
        foodArray.push(food);
        trace(foodArray.length)

        addChild(food); //adds the food to the board


        for (var i:uint = 0; i < snake.length; i++){
            if (rndY == snake[i].y && rndX == snake[i].x){ 
                placeFood();
            }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the food items to an array and loop through that array doing hitTestObject. Something like:

```
var foods:Array = new Array();
foods.push(makeItem(blah));
...
for each (food in foods) {
  food.hitTestObject(object);
}
```

Comment: hi i have amended my post with your idea. except it only returns the length as 1.

Comment: Declare foodArray outside your function. You don't want to create a new array each time, you want to append to the existing array.

Comment: thanks, i get you right its tracing the right array. now my snake object is in an array to. called snake. how i hit test that with the food array and make it trace something?

Comment: managed to code it with -  for each (food in foodArray) {
     if (food.hitTestObject(s)) {
  trace("hit");
  addSnake.stop();
  tmr.stop();
 } - however the hit test makes it so that when the snake passes a food object it detects it as a hit even if its one grid space out. any clue on how to fix this?

Comment: - http://ignitethatdesign.com/FlashLeaderBoard/hitTest.swf if you wanna see for yourself

Comment: hitTestObject will detect even slight overlap. Your objects look to be overlapping by a couple pixels. To fix that you should have a smaller invisible object parented to the food and do the hitTest with that instead of the entire food object.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're putting items on a fixed grid. Do the food items move around? Your food does not move, and your snake (or whatever collides with the food) does, you can greatly optimize your collision detection by figuring out what grid square(s) the moving object occupies and only checking against food in that local area.

Generally speaking, when you need to do collision detection between many objects, you do it in multiple passes. The first pass would consist of the least computationally expensive checks to cull things that could not possibly be colliding such as objects that are very far apart, moving away from each other, etc. Your next pass might be something like simple boundary box or circle tests. Lastly, when you're down to the few items that pass all the cheap tests, you can use more expensive and accurate hit tests like pixel-by-pixel ones between hit masks.

Comment: hi adam i have managed to get some sort of hit test working. but it seems that its a grid square out if you get me. you can look here i have uploaded the swf - http://ignitethatdesign.com/FlashLeaderBoard/hitTest.swf. if you try and miss the food object by one grid it detects it as a hit :/

Comment: Having just seen the game you posted, the problem is much simpler than I thought. You don't need any kind of collision detection in the usual sense, all you need is a grid of Booleans that tracks where the food is, and check that against the grid square that represents the head of your snake on each move of the snake.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed in the first place that the objects could be positioned arbitrarily, not movement constrained to a grid like this. I'm voting up this answer based on Adam's last comment.

Answer (score 1):

Another way avoiding arrays is to use a sprite that contains all food. Every sprite is a collection of sprites and therefore a tree. That's what I use for hit detection: 1 special sprite contains only enemies / food. Run through all children and you don't even need to check the types of them. Cast them if needed.

```
// begin
var foodCollection: Sprite = new Sprite();

// time passes, food is added
foodCollection.addChild(food);

// hit test
for (var i:int = 0; i < foodCollection.NumChildren; i++)
{
    var food: Sprite = foodCollection.getChildAt(i);
    // test
}
```